# File input inside contenteditable div not working on FireFox

Tags: html, file, input

I have a contenteditable div. Inside this div, there is an input file. However, this input file can't browse a file. When I delete the attribute of the contenteditable from the div, the input file is able to browse file. What's wrong?

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    <input type="file"/>
</div>

versus

<div>
    <input type="file"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me in Chrome. Which browser are you on? And any errors in the console?

Comment: I changed the example to a snippet, making this faster for others to test. I experience the same behavior in FF (and FF12). It does however seem to work in IE.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work in FF. I use FF. I love FF. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior (currently not on the [know-issues over at CanIUse for contenteditable](http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable)) for firefox.

The whatwg spec on [`contenteditable`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#contenteditable) states:

> The `contenteditable` content attribute is an [enumerated attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attribute) whose keywords are:
>   the **empty string**, `true`, and `false`.
>   The empty string and the `true` keyword map to the *true state*.
>   The `false` keyword maps to the *false state*.
>   In addition, there is a third state, the *inherit state*, which is the [missing value default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#missing-value-default) (and the [invalid value default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#invalid-value-default)).
>
> The *true state* indicates that the element is editable. The *inherit state* indicates that the element is editable if its parent is. The *false state* indicates that the element is not editable.

The [MDN entry on 'Content Editable'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) states:

> In HTML5 any element can be editable.

but then continues later-on:

> It can be used in almost all HTML elements.

yet, doesn't specify what elements it can (not) be used on.

These are my test-results for FireFox (noting that this doesn't appear to be a recent regression, FF12 behaves the same way):

```html
01 <input type="file" />                            WORKS              <br>
02 <input type="file" contenteditable="true" />     DOES NOT WORK      <br> 
03 <input type="file" contenteditable="" />         WORKS (wtf?)       <br>
04 <input type="file" contenteditable="false" />    WORKS              <br>
05 <input type="file" contenteditable="foobar" />   WORKS              <br>

<div>
  06 <input type="file" />                          WORKS
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  07 <input type="file" />                          DOES NOT WORK
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  <div contenteditable="false">
    08 <input type="file" />                        WORKS
  </div>
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  09 <input type="file" contenteditable="true" />   DOES NOT WORK
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  10 <input type="file" contenteditable="" />       DOES NOT WORK
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  11 <input type="file" contenteditable="false" />  DOES NOT WORK
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
  12 <input type="file" contenteditable="foobar" /> DOES NOT WORK
</div>

<button onclick="
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].setAttribute('contenteditable','false');
">set parent div for 07 to contenteditable="false" to make it WORK</button>
```

Note test 3 (a contradiction), 8 (although that's probably not what you want..) and 11 (which appears as a contradiction to me).

**Now, what I *expect* that is happening**,
 is that firefox-developers read <strike>Dungeons & Dragons</strike> [Drag & Drop model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#security-risks-in-the-drag-and-drop-model)'s security section 6.7.9:

> Consider a hostile page providing some content and getting the user to select and drag and drop (or indeed, copy and paste) that content to a victim page's `contenteditable` region. If the browser does not ensure that only safe content is dragged, potentially unsafe content such as scripts and event handlers in the selection, once dropped (or pasted) into the victim site, get the privileges of the victim site. **This would thus enable a cross-site scripting attack.**

and took that one step further (in trying to protect the user).
How is D&D related you ask? well.. select `01 [____][Browse] WORKS` from the running test-snippet and drag (& drop) it into (where the `^` is): `09 [____][Browse] DOES NO^T WORK`... (and see that the copy of the working input also doesn't work).

However, that doesn't explain test 3, or 8 or... (and I'm guessing at least test 3 is a bug), in fact.. I'm still scratching my head here; I understand some inheritance but this appears inconsistent.

**I'd Love to see someone post a better answer here** (I posted this as as answer as it is clearly to much for a comment, but don't feel this is a definitive answer either...)

**EDIT:**
I've added a button to the test that sets contenteditable to false for the parent div of test 7. Clicking it makes test 7 work.

That, actually, could be a solution (depending on what you are doing).
It appears that this behavior kind of enforces a 'model' of live WYSIWYG (optionally with raw source tab/area) AND and the actual live rendered thing ('preview').
Just like the three tabs in a mail-composer (for example): WYSIWYG, source, preview...
That means you could have a 'dummy' tab that, when activated, does nothing more than switch the contenteditable of the WYSIWYG editor area to false.
If need be (I didn't test so far) one could consider to copy the live innerHTML of the WYSIWYG area to a preview-area..
Thus, it appears that the solution is to adopt this model to support firefox..