# why my input element which is a div child is unclickable while when i replace this input by a button, the button is clickable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a div element which contains a button and an input element.
but when the input is in the div the input becomes unclickable

```js
var video_button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var user_area = document.createElement("DIV");
    var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
    
    function upload_video(e){
        console.log("upload_video function");
        var v = document.createElement("VIDEO");
        inp.onchange = function(e){
     v.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0]);
     v.style.heigth = "1000px";
     v.style.width = "1000px";
     user_area.appendChild(v);
        }
    }
    
    
    function input(e){
        console.log("input function");
        inp.setAttribute("type","file");
        user_area.appendChild(inp);
        inp.addEventListener("click",upload_video)
    }
    
    
    window.onload = function(){
        video_button.innerHTML = "upload a video";
        video_button.addEventListener("click",input);
        user_area.setAttribute("contentEditable","true");
        user_area.style.width = "100px";
        user_area.style.height = "500px";
        document.body.appendChild(user_area);
        user_area.appendChild(video_button);
    }
```

Comment: looks okay to me. while clicking the input file type (choose file) I can see a file upload window manager opens up.
Which button are you talking about ?

Comment: it works in chrome not in firefox. i don't know why.

Comment: I suggested an edit on your post, accept it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working on firefox because of the content editable attribute set to true. And there is a [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470023/file-input-inside-contenteditable-div-not-working-on-firefox) behind it.
If you don't need it that much, you can remove it.

```js
var video_button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var user_area = document.createElement("DIV");
var input_wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");

function upload_video(e){
    console.log("upload_video function");
    var v = document.createElement("VIDEO");
    inp.onchange = function(e){
    v.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0]);
    v.style.heigth = "1000px";
    v.style.width = "1000px";
    user_area.appendChild(v);
    }
}


function input(e){
    console.log("input function");
    inp.setAttribute("type","file");
    input_wrapper.setAttribute("contentEditable","false");
    user_area.appendChild(input_wrapper);
    input_wrapper.appendChild(inp);
    inp.addEventListener("click",upload_video)
}


window.onload = function(){
    video_button.innerHTML = "upload a video";
    video_button.addEventListener("click",input);
    user_area.setAttribute("contentEditable","true");
    user_area.style.width = "100px";
    user_area.style.height = "500px";
    document.body.appendChild(user_area);
    user_area.appendChild(video_button);
}
```

Comment: i need content editable because i want that my div looks like a text area which will allow user to write text and to upload file. i'm doing a news website.

Comment: how about you wrap your input element inside a container div which has the content editable attribute set to false, but still the original user_area which was set to content editable true stays the same way ? check the updated answer

Comment: yes it works, but can you explain to me why the contentEditable is an issue ?

Comment: I too tried to gather as much I could, it should have been the way chrome did it, basically content editable makes an element editable by the user. so, if a user wants to delete the button you created, he/she can do that. but the functionality should have worked as chrome did.
Still you can read carefully the "reason" link on the second sentence of my answer, 
Also have a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_contenteditable.asp) 
Or try some googling :)